# Can't import python modules with Nodejs and Python shell

Tags: python, node.js, npm, pip, frontend

I'm trying to run a python script through nodejs pythonshell but I keep getting a modulenotfound error when trying to import the libraries that I downloaded with pip. I installed pythonshell on my computer with npm, so I know that's not the problem.

Comment: Pls add some details about the error you're getting. Post it here.

Answer (score 1):

When you install packages you will install them to a directory named `site-packages`

In your main directory this can be found from:
`your-directory/lib/Python3.6/site-packages`

If you copy and paste the files you'd like to run into this folder, and change the script path accordingly, the file will find all imported modules.

This is because the python shell was looking in the current directory for your packages and not finding them.

Comment: I'm trying to make an application with multiple scripts and sub directories that will eventually get turned into an exe file, so I'm not sure how feasible this is.

Comment: Just try packaging it and see how it runs.

Comment: I tried placing my project folder inside the site-packages folder and I got the same error

Comment: It worked! Now I am not getting the modulenotfound error, but another error later in code  @Helix